# Gitkit Java client library - Trouble verifying token signature: Invalid audience

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

We're struggling with an issue during the token verification. We have the following exception:

```
java.security.SignatureException: Invalid audience: xxx-platform. Should be: 787384428332-32charsofidxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
    at com.google.identitytoolkit.JsonTokenHelper$AudienceChecker.check(JsonTokenHelper.java:67)
    at net.oauth.jsontoken.JsonTokenParser.verify(JsonTokenParser.java:156)
    at net.oauth.jsontoken.JsonTokenParser.verify(JsonTokenParser.java:103)
    at net.oauth.jsontoken.JsonTokenParser.verifyAndDeserialize(JsonTokenParser.java:116)
    at com.google.identitytoolkit.JsonTokenHelper.verifyAndDeserialize(JsonTokenHelper.java:46)
    at com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitClient.validateToken(GitkitClient.java:126)
    at com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitClient.validateTokenInRequest(GitkitClient.java:154)
    at com.some.package.user.GitKitUserService.getGitkitUserFromRequest(GitKitUserService.groovy:25)
```

We have checked many times the gitkit-server-config.json file, he seems to correct and points to a valid .p12 file. The p12 is correctly found and opened (since we have a FileNotFoundException when we remove it, or parsing error when we alter it...) but the validation fails because of a null verifier...
Here it is:

```
    {
    "clientId": "707385568332-32charsofidxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "projectId": "xxx-platform",
    "serviceAccountEmail": "xxx@xxx-platform.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile": "/an/existing/path/xxx-platform-44d0379d237c.p12",
    "widgetUrl": "https://example.com/authentication/authenticate",
    "cookieName": "gtoken"
    }
```

Of course we can provide any additional information that might be required, we're really stuck with this issue!

Thank in advance for any clue!

Comment: Tried swapping the clientId and projectId values? logout or use incognito mode when testing otherwise the old config may stay cached in the browser's token.

Comment: Hi Chomeh, Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes, we already did it many times, alas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just share my experience from setting up earlier today incase it can help you:

```
                        String token = cookie.getValue();

                        try {
                            GitkitClient gitkitClient = GitkitClient.newBuilder()
                                    .setGoogleClientId("206268081687-u5mg1cl3teeeo635vrsuj8uotdi7meqq.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                                    //.setGoogleClientId("effortless-edge-119904")
                                    .setServiceAccountEmail("tables@effortless-edge-119904.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                                    .setCookieName("gtoken")
                                    .setWidgetUrl("http://localhost:8080/gitkit")
                                    .setKeyStream(new ClassPathResource("tables-8271416a8e0c.p12").getInputStream()).build();

                            GitkitUser gitkitUser = gitkitClient.validateToken(token);
```

Gives me

```
java.security.SignatureException: Gitkit token audience(effortless-edge-119904) 
doesn't match projectId or clientId in server configuration
```

This works:

```
                        try {
                            GitkitClient gitkitClient = GitkitClient.newBuilder()
                                    .setGoogleClientId("effortless-edge-119904")
                                    .setServiceAccountEmail("tables@effortless-edge-119904.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                                    .setCookieName("gtoken")
                                    .setWidgetUrl("http://localhost:8080/gitkit")
                                    .setKeyStream(new ClassPathResource("tables-8271416a8e0c.p12").getInputStream()).build();

                            GitkitUser gitkitUser = gitkitClient.validateToken(token);
                                                    logger.info("Validated gitkit token");
```

Comment: WONDERFUL !!!! Thank you so much (as well as to DFB also of course). This works ! We must use like you the "project ID", instead of the client ID ! I think there is something confusing in the Gitkit naming convention, or I need some rest... Have a nice day, you saved mine !

Comment: I found it confusing as well, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I think DFB's answer is correct.

But we don't recommend hard-coded json config in Java code. There's a static method called [createFromJson](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitClient.java#L119) you can use to read json file and then initialize GitkitClient.

We'll also need to update the README in identity-toolkit-java-client. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and stumbled upon this thread. I was using gitclient-1.2.3.jar. I updated it to gitkitclient-1.2.5.jar (latest) and the problem went away.

UPDATE: I'm adding the code snippet below. I'm setting both `setGoogleClientId` and `setProjectId` as shown in the sample https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitClient.java

```
GitkitClient gitkitClient = new GitkitClient.Builder()  
    .setGoogleClientId("654028407702-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")  
    .setProjectId("my-project")  
    .setServiceAccountEmail("my-project@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com")  
    .setKeyStream(context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/identity/my-project-xxxxxxxxxxxx.p12"))  
    .setWidgetUrl("https://my-project.appspot.com/oauth2callback")  
    .setCookieName("gToken")  
    .setServerApiKey("AIzaSyAxQ7z5Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx")  
    .build();
```

Comment: Hello DFB, thanks a lot for your reply ! Unfortunately, I just double-checked and we were already using the 1.2.5 version: we have "compile 'com.google.identitytoolkit:gitkitclient:1.2.5'" in our build config file... Have a nice day, anyway, and thanks again for your support.

Comment: Glad it's working for you. I added my code snippet as well.

Comment: Hi @DFB, thanks for your reply, too. It's disturbing to see that your configuration, which follows Google's guides, works... I don't understand why I have to use the projectId for the clientId. Very annoying, even if it works. And I think that we're caught up by this misconfiguration later: for example, the password reset links that are sent by email are invalid (we have a "Your password reset link is invalid or expired" message when opening such a link.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the [gitkitclient.js source code](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-node-client/blob/master/lib/gitkitclient.js) and both **projectId** and **clientId** are added to the same **audiences** array.

After more tests I found out that you must only put the project ID ('my-project-name') in the gitkit-server-config.json file.
The nasty thing is that if you add it with a 'clientId' property name it is also working...

As far as I can see, the client ID (like 654028407702-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com) can be removed.