# Why do I get "Invalid token" unless I invert projectId and clientId?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-identity-toolkit

In order to setup Google Identity Toolkit for my Website I started with the [Quick-start App for Node.js](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/nodejs).

It worked fine on localhost.
But when I moved it to an actual app-engine instance it did not work anymore.
I got this error returned by gitkitClient.verifyGitkitToken():

> Invalid token: Unable to verify the ID Token: Wrong recipient, payload
>   audience != requiredAudience

I found [a very helpful post on stackoverflow about more or less the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948889/gitkit-java-client-library-trouble-verifying-token-signature-invalid-audience/34962116#34962116), for Java instead of node.js: It looks like there is a mismatch between projectId and clientId.

I changed my gitkit-server-config.json file to swap the **projectId** and **clientId** values and it worked!

- This sound very much like a major bug on google side, doesn't it?
- Why does it work on localhost?
- Will this be changed/fixed in the future?
- Maybe the problem is in the tutorial?

I have a working solution for now, but I do not feel safe to keep it like that...

I hope a googler will read this!

[EDIT]

Following wyhao31's comment I had a closer look at the [gitkitclient.js source code](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-node-client/blob/master/lib/gitkitclient.js) and both **projectId** and **clientId** are added to the same **audiences** array.
After more test I found out that you must only put the project ID ('my-project-name') in the gitkit-server-config.json file.
The nasty thing is that if you add it with a 'clientId' property name it is also working...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, and if you read gitkit-server-config.json file like this

```
var gitkitClient = new GitkitClient(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./gitkit-server-config.json')));
```

I think the problem might caused by using old nodejs client lib. Could you try to update your client lib to latest version(0.0.6)? Or you can use the [code](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-node-client) directly.